# Removing an image from a Frame (tkinter, PIL)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I had originally asked about adding an image to a tkinter Frame. The code I ended up with was as follows:

```
img_load = Image.open('D:\Downloads\Pictures\Python\PNG\\2C.png')
img_load = img_load.resize((140,200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
imgRender = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_load)
img = tk.Label(frame1, image=imgRender)
img.image = imgRender
```

That seems to work okay so far, but then came the case of my wanting to swap that image for another. I could just load another one in its place, but I suspect that may cause a memory leak.

I have come across the close method on the PIL Image object and I have tried to use it. I tied it to a button and then clicked it, with nothing happening - the image remained on screen in the frame, and so it is in memory. Just to be clear on what I'm doing, that code as follows:

```
img_load.close()
```

So it would seem that I'm going about this the wrong way. I do want an image added to a frame, so the code I've used for that works well. I just don't know how to unload that image in this situation.

So how do I do that?

Edit: I have two objects it seems I need to worry about. Image and PhotoImage. Both are created objects. I can use 'close' for the former, but there doesn't seem to be such a method for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to just update the label with the new Image that you want to display. The Garbage Collector will get rid of the old unused Image. 
Another point is, that you can close the Image the way you do, but that will not update the Label.

**The only way to update the label ist by calling:**

```
img.configure(image="new_image")
img.image="new_image"
```

After you have called that, you can still close the old Image with `img_load.close()` if you want to. But the Garbage Collector should do the Job either way...